# Why a form tag without action reloads the page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So we know that the `action` attribute used for sending the form data to a web server.

But I have a couple of questions:

- If the `action` attribute is not set, why does it reload the page by default?
- Shouldn't be the default behavior, not reload the page if it's not set?
- If there a spec to cover this case?
- In this times in javascript, we use a lot async server calls using SPA, and others Technics, is there a plan to change this in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `form` tag was always meant to submit the form to a server, and the original definition of the `action` attribute reflects this.

> The program that will handle the completed and submitted form (the [`action`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-action) attribute).

The [`action` attribute was actually a required attribute in HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) and thus would be invalid if not specified.

In [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attributes-for-form-submission) it is not required, but defaults to the current page's URL.

> The `action` IDL attribute must [reflect](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#reflect) the content attribute of the same name, except that on getting, when the content attribute is missing or its value is the empty string, [the document's address](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-document's-address) must be returned instead.

The `method` attribute controls how the `action` attribute will be called. Its default value is `GET`, meaning an HTTP call will be made.

> The *invalid value default* for these attributes (*ed.* the `method` and `formmethod`) is the [GET](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-method-get) state. The *missing value default* for the [`method`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-method) attribute is also the [GET](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-method-get) state.

Thus, if you don't specify either attribute, the default is to make an HTTP GET call to the page you are currently on. You should see any form element's names and values in the URL as query string parameters.

As far as I know, there are no plans to change these defaults, as it would break a large number of forms on the internet.

Comment: Good explanation! thanks a lot,  I don't think either  they will break the  Standard but add an attribute like `async` as they have been doing with other elements to improve the use of HTML and Javascript

Comment: There are no plans for changing the defaults because the main functionality of the form is to submit your input fields. If you don't want or plan to submit it you mostly don't need the form element.

Comment: I don't think the intent is to not submit the data, @Stephan, but rather to submit it via ajax or some other mechanism besides the standard method.

Comment: I meant submitting via the form. If one posts the data via Ajax the form element isn't needed.

Comment: Not strictly necessary, but there are a number of things the `form` element provides that are nice (not least of which is a single source of validity information).

Answer (score 2):

The form's action attribute defines to which location the form data should be posted, the default value is the current location. So in your case the form generates a GET action to the current page, which you probably don't handle on your server, which therefore just again returns the page.

If you use JavaScript to deal with your data and AJAX requests to post it you maybe don't even need to use forms. If you want to use a form and not reload the page, you have to call `event.preventDefault();` in the form's submit handler.

Comment: The default action is `GET`!

Comment: No, the action is the url, and therefore defaults to your current url by what Stephan is saying, the method may well default to get. Either way, the form will post or get to your current url. Causing the reload.