# Why does 'remove item from array' cause app reload?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

Working on a react/RTK project, I tried to make an action to remove an item from a list.

```
       removeFromList: (state, action) =>{
       state.list.filter((city) => city.id 
       !== action.payload)},
```

Unfortunatelly, when the button is clicked, it causes a full app reload!

```
function Gradcard({i}) {

  const deleteIt = (i)=> {
       removeFromList(i)
  }
  return (
  <>
    <div>{i}</div>
    <button onClick={deleteIt}>Delete</button> 
    </>
  )
}
```

My initial state is:

```
const initialState = {
  city: '',
  isFavorite: false,
  list: [],
  pending: false,
  err: false
}
```

The list generating function:

```
{cities.map((i)=>{
        return <Gradcard key={i.city} i={i} />
      }
```

and selector:

```
const cities = useSelector((state) => state.api.list);
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Can you create a minimal, reproducible example on codesandbox?

Comment: here goes: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-grothendieck-0ywef2

Answer (score 0):

The default type of a [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type) is `submit`.

> `submit`: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified for buttons associated with a , or if the attribute is an empty or invalid value.

So it will submit a form, and the form element will submit the form data to the server. This is the default behavior of a form element, and the default HTTP method used to submit the form is [`GET`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-method).

Open the console and switch the network tab, you can see there is a GET HTTP request sent to the current SPA url, it will reload your SPA.

The solution is to use [e.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent the default behavior of the button, or use specify a `button` type.

```
const deleteIt = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(removeFromList(i));
  };
```

Or,

```
<button type='button' onClick={deleteIt}>Delete</button>
```

[image]

Also, see this [Why a form tag without action reloads the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337773/why-a-form-tag-without-action-reloads-the-page)

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-shtern-ckd2sq?file=/src/comps/Gradcard.js)

Comment: Changing button type gave a non-serializable item error. Adding the e.preventDefault does not stop the re-render...

Comment: @ydrea I added the codesandbox link.

Comment: yes, and it doesn't work... especially without referencing the 'i' variable...